# Odata $select Query taking time

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am having a Web Api2 application. Currently I am using odata v4. 
Earlier my Sqlite DB table had 200 records now it increases to 9000 records.

Now While getting records

```
http://localhost:51728/odata/Content?$select=Id,Name
```

It is taking almost 40 secs. 
in controller I am using

```
return OK(GetContentMethod())
```

In **GetContentMethod()** I am fetching all fields. (15 fields/column).
I am using EF6 with repository pattern. Any idea how to improve the performance?

Or Any particular method I have to write for $select operation?

Comment: What type does `GetContentMethod` return?

Comment: You know you can just return `IQueryable<T>` from the controller action and the OData part will take care of only querying the necessary stuff?

Comment: @TomDoesCode: The GetContentMethod returns ** IQueryable<Content>**.

The Content Entity also have child Entity.

Comment: @juunas: I am thinking that the Content Entity I am fetching from db & later I am calling the navigation entities in client.

Should I Include navigation property too while doing `context.Content`